# Sequelize: preview sync query without executing it

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make an application with node.js and sequelize ORM. I learnt about the function `Sequelize.sync()` to update database schema based on the app model.

Is there a way to log the SQL statements that `Sequelize.sync()` would run **without executing them**?
I'm used to Doctrine ORM where such a thing is possible and quite convenient (it allows to double-check your model before actually persisting it to the DB).
Is there a way to do it with sequelize too?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `force: false` option in `sync`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do what I want unfortunately. The `force: false` only determines whether or not you want to delete tables in the sync, but it executes the queries anyway.

Comment: I see. In that case, you want to specify which query that you want to make it happen virtually. With `force: false` addition/modification/deletion of columns in existing table shouldn't happen. Other type of query could be executed.